# One query for multiple where?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Query which gets the **average score** from the **answers** table, And groups it by the category which the question is in.

This query gets the desired result for answers **where the coach_id = 0**
This is the desired result in which for every coach_id i get another row

[image]

**Now my question is:** Is it possible to also get the same answers from the same table ( so almost the same query ) but where the coach_id = 1 or coach_id = 2.. in the same query?##

This is my query

```
SELECT
    ROUND((SUM(score) / COUNT(vragen.id) * 10),1) as score
FROM antwoorden
JOIN vragen
    ON vragen.id = antwoorden.vraag_id
JOIN categorieen
    ON categorieen.id = vragen.categorie_id
WHERE antwoorden.werknemer_id = 105 AND antwoorden.coach_id = 0
GROUP BY categorieen.id
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a conditional sum, I think.

Column score_0, that gets the average score for coach_id = 0.
Column score_1, that gets the average score for coach_id = 1.

The count will not work  neither, as count ... counts everything! Both coach_id 0 and 1. So you'll have to use a conditional sum there, too.

Besides you'll need the coach_id filter suggested by Neville K.

So:

```
SELECT
    ROUND((
        SUM(CASE WHEN antwoorden.coach_id = 0 THEN score ELSE 0 END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN antwoorden.coach_id = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 10
    ), 1) as score_0,
    ROUND((
        SUM(CASE WHEN antwoorden.coach_id = 1 THEN score ELSE 0 END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN antwoorden.coach_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 10
    ), 1) as score_1
FROM antwoorden
JOIN vragen
    ON vragen.id = antwoorden.vraag_id
JOIN categorieen
    ON categorieen.id = vragen.categorie_id
WHERE antwoorden.werknemer_id = 105 AND antwoorden.coach_id IN (0,1)
GROUP BY categorieen.id
```

I think this is what you meant.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm gonna take a very long look at this to try and understand. Loving sql more and more! :)

Comment: Brainteaser! What if there would be an x amount of coaches.. So the number is not defined. Or am i better to process that in PHP?

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure if you could handle all that in SQL without a store procedure. You can group by coach_id, then sum the scores in one column and counting the records in another, then sending that to php to make the rounding, would be easier?

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided your table schemas I would have a hard time writing the query for your actual example. What you want is the `SUM(IF(...))` pattern, aggregating on a conditional:

```
SELECT
  foo_id,
  SUM(IF(bar_id = 1, baz, 0)) as sum_baz_bar_1,
  SUM(IF(bar_id = 2, baz, 0)) as sum_baz_bar_2,
  SUM(IF(bar_id = 3, baz, 0)) as sum_baz_bar_3
FROM table
WHERE ...
GROUP BY foo_id
```

You need to think carefully about your aggregation functions when using this pattern, especially with `COUNT` or other functions that deal with the presence of a value (such as `0`) rather than the value of it.

If you post your table schemas (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`) or even better set up a sample data set on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com), I would be happy to help show how to do it with your actual schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can use the `in` clause

```
... antwoorden.coach_id in (0, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question isn't clear. I want the results for coach_id = 1 in another column :) i'll add it to my question